# Sending a notification email to helpdesk after user registered (FuelSDK/PHP)

Tags: fuel-sdk, notification, triggered-send

I'm using FuelSDK in PHP. Just developed a page allowing users to register. Once the user has successfully been added in the Data Extension, I'd like to send a notification email to our customer care service, i.e. always the same recipient. It doesn't have to be an HTML email. Where do I start with this? Do I have to create a new Data Extension for triggered sends + an email template? Or is there a simpler way, similar to the PHP mail() function?